# tcpdump cannot capture none-broadcast/multicast packets from bridge interface in OpenWRT

Tags: linux-networking, bridge, tcpdump, openwrt

(Originally, I posted it on StackOverflow. I move it to networkengineering and then here.)

I have TP-LINK WR841N v9 router and install OpenWRT firmware `CHAOS CALMER (15.05.1, r48532)`.

I have `/etc/config/network` content:

`config interface 'lan'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '10.15.252.3'
    option netmask '255.255.254.0'
    option gateway '10.15.252.1'
    option ifname 'eth0 eth1'`

Here is the output of `ip link ls`:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-lan state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-lan state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

I have two computers cable-connecting to 2 of the 4 LAN ports. Let's say computer `A` and `B`.

1. `A` keeps pinging `B` and it works well.
2. On the router, I use `tcpdump` to captuer traffic from bridge `br-lan`: `tcpdump -i br-lan -n 'arp or icmp'`.

I did see `arp` traffic, but there are **no ICMP** traffic.

I tried to setup iptables rules to block traffic to `B` in both `INPUT` and `output` chain, and it's not working.

Here is the output of command `brctl` and `ip`:

`bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-lan      7fff.c46e1fb68e24   no      eth0
                            eth1`

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    63107      580      0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    63107      580      0       0       0       0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-lan state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    64256004   445450   0       6       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    8775980    43685    0       0       0       0
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-lan state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    0          0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    0          0        0       0       0       0
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    0          0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    0          0        0       0       0       0
5: br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether c4:6e:1f:b6:8e:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    57777761   444757   0       60579   0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    8871188    44499    0       0       0       0`

There are surely lots of `TX` and `RX` packets on interfaces.

So, my questions are:
1. How to use tcpdump to caputer traffic flow through bridge `br-lan`? (Bridge works on layer-2 and it is suppose to work, isn't it?)
2. If I want to mirror traffic in/out of computer B to another port(e.g `wan` port), what should I do? (**I tried to use this [port-mirroring tool](https://github.com/mmaraya/port-mirroring), but it is not working.**)

(I want to try `ebtables`, but I couldn't get it installed on the router due to insufficient space. Also, I couldn't find tool `bridge` to check the forward DB on the bridge.)

I found another relevant thread: [Tcpdump/Iptables on bridge interface without assigned IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/692952/tcpdump-iptables-on-bridge-interface-without-assigned-ip-address) and [tcpdump on bridge interface (virbr) does not receive any packets destined for one of its addresses](https://serverfault.com/questions/743466/tcpdump-on-bridge-interface-virbr-does-not-receive-any-packets-destined-for-on?rq=1), but it's not working.

Comment: Bridges learn which MAC addresses are connected to which interfaces, and they only send traffic to the interface where the MAC address is connected. On the other hand, ARP is broadcast, meaning that it is sent to every interface on a bridge.

Comment: @RonMaupin TCPDUMP cannot get packets before it sends out to the right "LAN" ports of the router?  TCPDUMP picks the packets right after the interface fetches it.

Comment: Don't confuse bridges and routers. Bridges operate at layer-2, and routers operate at layer-3. A WAN interface is a layer-3 interface, but a switch interface is a layer-2 interface. You don't mirror layer-2 traffic to a layer-3 interface. A layer-3 device, e.g. router, strips off the layer-2 fraem to get to the layer-3 packet, and it creates a new frame for the new interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, got that. Mirroring to WAN interface is not correct. Still, how can I use tcpdump to capture unicast packets **flow through** the bridge? From the output of  `ip link` command, `br-lan` is already in **PROMISC** mode. I starts thinking the TCPDUMP is buggy.

Comment: @RonMaupin Also, there are 4 LAN **physical** port on the router. But, the `ifconfig` command-alike only shows 2 physical ports **eth1** and **eth0**, and they are attached to `br-lan` bridge. I am not an hardware guy, but it really confused me.

Comment: With bridges, you capture frames (layer-2), not packets (layer-3). Are you certain that the frames are passing through the bridge interface? If the source and destination MAC addresses are outside the same interface, the bridge interface will never see the frames. You should capture the frames that originate outside of one ethernet interface and are destined out the other ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have reconfigured the router to do the followings:
1. Assign both **eth0** and **eth1** to bridge `br-lan`;
2. cable-connect computer **B** to **eth1** port (**wan** port);
3. In port-mirroring config file, forward traffic from **eth1** to IP of **A**.

Now, I can listen all the traffics in/out of **B**. And of course, tcpdump can also capture traffic flow through br-lan.